# iPad keyboard is now small

Tags: keyboard, ipad, ipados, multi-touch

The keyboard on my iPad has just started floating and so is now much smaller and very difficult to use.

How do I get it back to go full size on the bottom of the screen. Note the way described in this Apple document https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210758 does **NOT** work. Spreading fingers on the keyboard does nothing. Ideally some non gesture way as I find  gestures are impossible to remember.

Secondly how can I stop this from ever happening again?

Comment: I had this as well after using the Apple Pencil for a bit in an app. The only way I found to get the full keyboard back was to force quit the app and relaunch.

Answer (score 6):

When the small keyboard is floating, there's a grabbar at the bottom of the small keyboard. Touch and hold it, the small keyboard can now be dragged. Now drag it to the middle-bottom of the screen. The keyboard should turn into a big grey rectangle. When you release it, the keyboard "docks" to the bottom and becomes normal again.

Comment: On iOS 17 this gails. And is stuck do I can’t see where I am typing

Answer (score 0):

Two finger pinch-to-zoom “in” (fingers move apart) on the keyboard. It will expand to the large one again.

Comment: No it did not which is why I asked the question