# How to switch keyboard to normal view in Chrome?

Tags: keyboard, ipad, google-chrome, ipados, apple-pencil

Something happened and onscreen keyboard (in Google Chrome) on my iPad Pro 11" was switched to small mode.

> [image]

Is's not clear what is happened and how to switch it back to normal view. In Safari it has normal view:

> [image]

I'm on iPadOS 16.3

My issue seems slightly different than in  [iPad keyboard is now small](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/452490/ipad-keyboard-is-now-small), where floating keyboard can be moved to the bottom and expanded to normal view. In my case this doesn't work, and as you can see in my case there is small addition floating window with "undo, top/up, mic, enter" buttons, that not exist while regular floating keyboard is displayed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iPad keyboard is now small](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/452490/ipad-keyboard-is-now-small)

Comment: @tama it seems that my case is slightly different, since floating keyboard discussed on links provided by you can be moved to the bottom and expanded to normal view. But in my case this doesn't work, and as you can see in my case there is small addition floating window with "undo, top/up, mic, enter", that not exist while regular floating keyboard is displayed.

Comment: Did you try the "pinch-out gesture" on the keyboard itself?    This is called the [floating keyboard](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/383180/119271) and this is the normal behavior. The keyboard is "different" because it has been updated since the questions have been asked/answered.  It still operates the exact same way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disabling the  Scribble feature of the Apple pencil resolves the issue.  It's not ideal if you use that feature. *Settings → Apple Pencil → Scribble*

Restarting Chrome resolves the issue; the full size keyboard appears again. But, using the Pencil, with Scribble enabled will cause the small keyboard and small tool bar to appear. Two finger gesture to expand the keyboard does not work. When the small keyboard appears the small toolbar appears as well.

Comment: As I said before on deleted answer there's no need to restart Chrome. Switching the tab is enough.